# How to check number being entered in textbox dynamically?

Tags: javascript

i have 5 textbox like

```
<input type ="text" size="3" name="r"><br>
<input type ="text" size="3" id="1" onchange="vali(this.id)" name="I"><br>
<input type ="text" size="3" name="a"><br>
<input type ="text" size="3" name="s"><br>
<input type ="text" size="3"  name="e">
function vali(d){
if(document.getElementById(d).value <0 || document.getElementById(d).value >=30)}
```

I want user should enter only max 2 digits on each field between 0 & 30. I'm not able to restrict user to enter only 2 digits in field, for example when user enters 151, 15 should come on 1st field and then focus will go on 2nd field automatically and remaining digits will be entered in 2nd field and will be there till the user enters another digit. After entering focus will come on field 3 like this. Also I need to check to each field contain a number between 0 and 30 which I'm checking in above code.
Also when user submit the form all field should be checked for value between (0 to 30) If there is any field present alert bos should pop up  else go to next page.i m not able to do this part .this is my form part above the 5 input field

```
<form name="detail" action ="selectjzone.jsp" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
```

and edited  part is

```
if (num < 0) {
alert("The value enteres for " +" " + document.getElementById(obj.id).name + " " +  "is  outside the range0 to 30" );
return false;
} else if (num > 30) {
alert("The value enteres for " +" " + document.getElementById(obj.id).name + " "+      "is  outside the range0 to 30" );
return false;
}
    return true;
```

}

Comment: Can you use a javascript framework such as jquery or dojo or are you restricted to pure javascript ?

Comment: javascript as i dont know jquery or other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a start at how to validate the field and move any extra to the next field:

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vpTq5/

HTML:

```
<input id="a" type ="text" size="3" onkeyup="validate(this, 'b')" name="r"><br>
<input id="b" type ="text" size="3" onkeyup="validate(this, 'c')" name="I"><br>
<input id="c" type ="text" size="3" onkeyup="validate(this, 'd')" name="a"><br>
<input id="d" type ="text" size="3" onkeyup="validate(this, 'e')" name="s"><br>
<input id="e" type ="text" size="3" onkeyup="validate(this)" name="e">
```

Javascript:

```
function validate(obj, next) {
    // fetch value and remove any non-digits
    // you could write more code to prevent typing of non-digits
    var orig = obj.value;
    var mod = orig.replace(/\D/g, "");
    var nextObj;
    // check length and put excess in next field
    if (mod.length > 2) {
        // shorten the current value
        obj.value = mod.substring(0,2);
        if (next) {
            // put leftover into following value
            var nextObj = document.getElementById(next);
            if (!nextObj.value) {
                nextObj.value = mod.substring(2);
                nextObj.focus();
            }
        }
    } else {
        // only set this if necessary to prevent losing cursor position
        if (orig != mod) {
            obj.value = mod;
        }
    }
    // convert to number and check value of the number
    var num = Number(obj.value);

    // don't know what you want to do here if the two digit value is out of range
    if (num < 0) {
        obj.value = "0";
    } else if (num > 30) {
        obj.value = "30";
    }
}
```

Some notes:

1. Id values on HTML objects cannot start with a digit.  They must start with a letter.
2. You will have to decide what behavior you want when a number greater than 30 is entered.
3. Keep in mind that input field values are strings.  If you want to treat them like a number, you have to convert them to be numeric.
4. With more code, you can actually prevent the typing of non-numeric keys and you can move the focus before the 3rd value is typed.
5. There are ways to get data into fields that does not trigger onkeyup (copy/paste, drag/drop) so you will have to validate at other times too.
6. If you can use a framework like jQuery, this can be done in a simpler way.

Comment: hey this is working but when i am submitting the form i want it should give alert message for the first field in order from 1 to 5 whose value is out of range>30 or<0.I thought i can do that part but its not working.I used <form action ="selectjzone.jsp" onsubmit="return validate(this)">  & inserted code here..if (num < 0) {
alert("0 to 30" );
     return false;
    } else if (num > 30) {
alert("0 to 30" );
        return false;
        }
        return true;
}

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "should give alert message for the top field".  Also, you haven't included any relevant code/HTML in your original question for the submit so we don't know what you already have.

Comment: actually i need when user enter value >30 or <0 alert message should be displayed and value entered should be left as it is if he enters 47 alert msg should be given asking him to enter in range 0 to 30.but 47 which was entered should be left as it is

Comment: if he enters 47 alert msg should be given asking him to enter in range 0 to 30.but 47 which was entered should be left as it is.when the user submit the form then alert message will ask him to enter the value in correct range.If more than 1 field contain wrong value the top most field name should be flash eg. if 2 field and 4th field contain >30 value alert box should flash 2 field name...

Comment: 1st.if (num < 0) {
alert("0 to 30" );
     return false;
    } else if (num > 30) {
alert("0 to 30" ); return false;}return true;}this part is your last codeing line. and second is <form action ="selectjzone.jsp"onsubmit="return validate(this)"

Comment: @saum22 - please don't put multiple lines of code in comments.  It is not readable.  Put it in your original question if you need to and post a comment telling people you've added it.  I added a form of error display to my example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vpTq5/.  Putting something like this into your own page design is up to you.  If you want to check all fields upon submit and then show something different, you will have to implement that code in your submit handler.

Comment: hey i have done that only  using onsubmit ,pls see my edited question..but i m not able to get it ,rest is all your code only.After clicking submit it is going to next page only without giving any alert box

Comment: I added a `validateAll()` option to my example so you can see how that works.  You can use that in onsubmit and change to an alert if you want.  In general alerts are not very user-friendly for most validation things which is why I haven't used them here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for automatic focusing on next field when you keep on typing,

you need to take of validating number between 0 & 30. Hope this helps,

```
<script>
var isNN = (navigator.appName.indexOf("Netscape")!=-1);
function chkEvent(e){
    var keyCode = (isNN) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if(e.shiftKey==1 && keyCode == 9) return false;
    if(e.shiftKey==1 || keyCode == 9 || keyCode == 16) return false;
    return true;
}
function autoTab(current,to, e) {
    var keyCode = (isNN) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    var filter = (isNN) ? [0,8,9] : [0,8,9,16,17,18,37,38,39,40,46];
    if(current.getAttribute && current.value.length == current.getAttribute("maxlength") && !containsElement(filter,keyCode)) to.focus();
    function containsElement(arr, ele) {
        var found = false, index = 0;
        while(!found && index < arr.length) if(arr[index] == ele) found = true; else index++;
        return found;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>

<input type ="text" size="3" maxlength="2" name="r" onkeyup="if(chkEvent(event)){return autoTab(this, document.getElementById('1'), event);}"><br>
<input type ="text" size="3" maxlength="2" id="1" onkeyup="if(chkEvent(event)){return autoTab(this, document.getElementById('a'), event);}" name="I"><br>
<input type ="text" size="3" maxlength="2" id="a" name="a" onkeyup="if(chkEvent(event)){return autoTab(this, document.getElementById('s'), event);}"><br>
<input type ="text" size="3" maxlength="2" id="s" name="s" onkeyup="if(chkEvent(event)){return autoTab(this, document.getElementById('e'), event);}"><br>
<input type ="text" size="3"  maxlength="2" id="e" name="e" >
```

Comment: also you can try altering the code for making text box accepts only numbers by playing with e.keyCode

Answer (score 0):

Use maxlength attribute to limit number of input

```
maxlength="2"
```

After settting the above you can use onkeyup event to check the length and change focus

```
       $('#target').keyup(function () {
            var maxlength = $(this).attr('maxlength');
            if ($(this).val().trim().length == maxlength){
               //change focus to next input
                //change focus to next input
                var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find(':input');
                inputs.eq(inputs.index(this) + 1).focus();
            }  
        });
```

Comment: I don't think that makes focus on next field after it hit the max length, tried it?

Comment: Here is a tutorial for counting the number of characters in a text field.
You should be able to use it in conjunction with a text change event to set the focus when you reach 2 characters

http://www.reconn.us/character_counter.html

Comment: @alFReDNSH that is how I would do it in jQuery

Comment: That attaches an eventHandler to each input... I think it's better to use event delegation on a wrapper div... see http://davidwalsh.name/delegate-event

Answer (score 0):

Here is pure javascript solution is it like what you wanted at all?

http://jsfiddle.net/rfyC8/

Code:

```
var ieEvents = !!document.attachEvent,
    addEvent = ieEvents ? "attachEvent" : "addEventListener",
        keyUp = ieEvents ? "onkeyup" : "keyup";

function validator( e ) {
var sib, intValue, val = this.value;
    if( val.length >= 2 ) {

    intValue = parseInt( val, 10 );

        if( isNaN( intValue ) || intValue < 0 || intValue > 30 ) {
        this.value = "";
        return false;   
        }

    sib = this.nextSibling;
        while( sib && sib.className != "textfield" ) {
        sib = sib.nextSibling;   
        }

        if( sib ) {
        sib.focus();
        }
        else {
        return false;   
        }
    }

}

document.getElementById("textfields")[addEvent]( keyUp,

    function(){
    var e = arguments[0] || window.event,
        target = e.target || e.srcElement;

        if( target.className == "textfield" ) {

        validator.call( target, e );
        }

    },

    false
);
```